# regex use with numpy and panda

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I try in a column to recover the cell if by doing a regex or an IN but impossible

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

cycling = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'qty' : ['RONCQ_A2_OPTI_SRV_S3','RONCQ_A3_SRV_S3','RONCQ_A2_TEMP_SRV_S3','RONCQ_A2_SRV_S3','RONCQ_A2_PC_SRV_S3'],
    }
)
cycling['col3'] = np.where("_OPTI" in cycling['qty'], cycling['qty'], 'autre')      


print(cycling)


#out result hope
#                    qty   col3
#0  RONCQ_A2_OPTI_SRV_S3  RONCQ_A2_OPTI_SRV_S3
#1       RONCQ_A3_SRV_S3  autre
#2  RONCQ_A2_TEMP_SRV_S3  autre
#3       RONCQ_A2_SRV_S3  autre
#4    RONCQ_A2_PC_SRV_S3  autre
```

in advance thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
cycling['col3'] = np.where(cycling['qty'].str.contains("_OPTI"), cycling['qty'], 'autre')
print(cycling)
```

**Output**

```
                    qty                  col3
0  RONCQ_A2_OPTI_SRV_S3  RONCQ_A2_OPTI_SRV_S3
1       RONCQ_A3_SRV_S3                 autre
2  RONCQ_A2_TEMP_SRV_S3                 autre
3       RONCQ_A2_SRV_S3                 autre
4    RONCQ_A2_PC_SRV_S3                 autre
```

From the documentation on [contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html#pandas.Series.str.contains):

> Return boolean Series or Index based on whether a given pattern or
> regex is contained within a string of a Series or Index.

If you are interested, the correct way to use the `in` expression for a Series would be:

```
cycling['col3'] = np.where(["_OPTI" in x for x in cycling['qty']], cycling['qty'], 'autre')
```

but I do **not recommend** this.

To find the negation of the predicate, do:

```
cycling['col3'] = np.where(~cycling['qty'].str.contains("_OPTI"), cycling['qty'], 'autre')
print(cycling)
```

**Output**

```
                    qty                  col3
0  RONCQ_A2_OPTI_SRV_S3                 autre
1       RONCQ_A3_SRV_S3       RONCQ_A3_SRV_S3
2  RONCQ_A2_TEMP_SRV_S3  RONCQ_A2_TEMP_SRV_S3
3       RONCQ_A2_SRV_S3       RONCQ_A2_SRV_S3
4    RONCQ_A2_PC_SRV_S3    RONCQ_A2_PC_SRV_S3
```

Notice the `~` in the front. Another option is,

```
cycling['col3'] = np.where(cycling['qty'].str.contains("_OPTI").eq(False), cycling['qty'], 'autre')
```

Comment: 134 / 5000
Résultats de traduction
hello, this works perfectly, I tried to do the reverse answer cycling ['qty']. str.contains ("_ OPTI") == false  but without success